# Meaning of the last sentence of the kaddish?

Tags: theology, translation, kaddish

The last sentence of the kaddish - "עושה שלום במרומיו" -refers to Gd making peace on high.

What does that mean?  Is peace considered the opposite of chaos?  Could someone restate the last sentence of the kaddish in different words?

Comment: Clarification - do you want to know the concept of what it means to "make peace in the 'high place'" or what "peace" in general really means here within the context of Kaddish? You might want to edit your focus in this question - they are very different topics.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Job.25.2?lang=Bi

Comment: @DanF  Yes, what it means to "make peace in the 'high place".

Answer (score 2):

The complete text you are quoting from Kaddish requests that G-d *make peace*, as in making complementing harmony, *completeness and perfection* (שלמות) both in the Heavens above and below, upon us.

That part of the revelation of G-d's unity is the complementary harmony between the angelic realms (במרומיו, Shamayim, Heavens) and what it influences below in the physical, material plane of existence.

This lower, material plane is also sometimes referred to as Malchut in kabbalistic literature. This state of complementary harmony is alluded to in the Roshei Teivot of the words Shamayim (**ש**מים) and Malchut (**מ**לכות) which forms the word *Name* (שם, ש״ם).

This is what is expressed in the [Zohar 2:135a:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.135a.8?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which we also say at [Kabbalat Shabbat](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42804&st=&pgnum=94) just before reciting Shema for the evening. The text is:

> כְּגַוְונָא **דְּאִינּוּן מִתְיַיחֲדִין לְעֵילָּא בְּאֶחָד, אוּף הָכִי אִיהִי, אִתְיַחֲדַת לְתַתָּא בְּרָזָא דְּאֶחָד, לְמֶהוֵי עִמְּהוֹן לְעֵילָּא חַד לָקֳבֵל חַד**, קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא אֶחָד לְעֵילָּא, לָא יָתִיב עַל כּוּרְסְיָיא דִּיקָרֵיהּ, עַד דְּאִיהִי אִתְעֲבִידַת בְּרָזָא דְּאֶחָד כְּגַוְונָא דִּילֵיהּ, לְמֶהֱוֵי אֶחָד בְּאֶחָד. **וְהָא (קל''ד ע''א) אוֹקִימְנָא רָזָא דַּיְיָ' אֶחָד וּשְׁמוֹ אֶחָד.**

Comment: I would appreciate a translation of the quoted passage. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly where in Kabbalat Shabbat?  (Just before the Shema is the 2nd blessing and before the borachu is a kaddish d'rabbanan.)

Comment: @YehudaW Per your request, a link illustrating has been provided.

Comment: @Yehuda the piece he refers to is not in Kabbalat Shabbat in all rites

Comment: Thank you.  In one siddur I just checked (Birnbaum), the 93rd Psalm is followed by kaddish yatom, without the material you quote. What siddur did you quote?

Comment: @YehudaW Double is correct. The text can be found in the Sephardi nusach, that of the Ari z"l, Chabad and others. Not sure about the siddur of the Vilna Gaon. Nusach Ashkenaz doesn't say it and I don't think it is found by the Yaacov Emden siddur either. I'm not sure what Birnbaum follows.

Comment: Most Birnbaum siddurm are Nusach Ashkenaz, and I don't think you will see this in any Nusach Ashkenaz siddur. However, I was surprised to discover that a while ago, Birnbaum published a series of Nusach Sefard siddurim. If you can locate it, he has an English translation. I also think that the Chaba"d *Tehillat Hashem's* English translation does a nice job translating this. Though, IMO, Zohar is tough to understand even in translation.

Answer (score 1):

"עושה שלום במרומיו"...

G-d created myriads of good angels and myriads of bad angels, all in Heaven. Those are pro-Semitic and others anti-semitic - can you imagine what's going on there? So G-d makes peace between all His servants in Heaven and everyone behaves.

I wish He did the same on the Earth too.